# html.ActionLink put a logo with CSS using a class, logo is never showing up

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to put a logo using the CSS but it is not showing up.
I tried using the class=site-title

_Layout.cshtml

```
     <body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </section>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Categorie", "Index", "Categorie")</li>
                        <li>@{Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "Panier");}</li>
```

CSS

```
 .site-title {
     color: #c8c8c8;
     font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
     font-size: 2.3em;
     margin: 0;
 }

 .site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
      background: none;
      color: #c8c8c8;
     outline: none;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 .site-title {
     background: url(../Images/htc_magic_black_open2.jpg) no-repeat top left;
     display: block;
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
     text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */
     }
```

I also tried with this

```
 <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "logo" 
     })</p>
```

Also tried this

```
 <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home" ,null, new { @class = 
   "logo" })</p>
```

and the CSS changed to

```
 .logo {
     background: url(../Images/htc_magic_black_open2.jpg) no-repeat top left;
     display: block;
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
     text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */
     }
```

but I left the class=site-title in front.  Any suggestion ?

Comment: dont know if this is your problem, but you css seems to mis-spelled .site-tile {, this should be .site-title

Comment: @TYY thanks but that didn't fix the problem, nothing is showing up

Comment: Is the CSS file correctly being loaded on the page? <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />.  It probably is, but just to be sure, its always good to check.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment as I am newly registered, so unfortunately it has to go in the Answers box...

If you replace the relative "../Images/htc_magic_black_open2.jpg" path with a full URL (i.e. http://www.example.com/images/htc_magic_black_open2.jpg) does the image appear? That would identify if it is a relative path issue.

If you add a "background-color: red" class to your .site-title class, does the box go red? If not, perhaps your CSS isn't being applied.

Comment: I tried the image inside the top BROWSER url and it works.  But the background-color: red didn't work

Comment: Hi. Do you mean adding the full image path into the CSS worked and the logo displayed? The background-color was just test whether the CSS was being recognised. If you didn't see it, perhaps the path to the stylesheet is wrong?

Comment: I put in the URL the full path of the images and it displayed. I tried the backgrouund-color: red in the two site-title from the css but no red is coming out

Comment: So is the problem solved if the image is now showing?

Comment: it is not working from the CSS.  I can reach the image starting the web site and then modifying the url to map to the image path

Comment: If you edit your CSS to the following, you don't get red background?

 .site-title {
     background-color: red;
     font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
     font-size: 2.3em;
     margin: 0;
 }

 .site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
      color: #c8c8c8;
     outline: none;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

Comment: Is the background:none on .site-title a affecting the display?

Comment: yes it is now working the red color is showing up, this means the css is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the logo is showing up.  The css was not refreshing.  I closed everything including Visual Studio and I tried with the background-color: red and it finally showing up.  I deleted the background-color: red; and I added the logo.  Thanks for your help.

Here is the css I used.

```
 .site-title {
    color: #c8c8c8;
    font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    margin: 0; 
    background: url(../Images/large-logo.png) no-repeat top left;
    display: block;
    width: 602px;
    height: 132px;
```